# Python MySQL Bulk Insertion Error with Character Encode

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas, mysql-python

I Start new Project in **Python** with **MySQL**.

I just try to insert millions of record from **CSV** to **MySQL** through **MySQLdb** package.

**My Code:**

```
 import pandas as pd 
 import MySQLdb

 #Connect with MySQL
 db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','****','MY_DB')
 cur = db.cursor()

 #Reading CSV
 df = pd.read_csv('/home/shankar/LAB/Python/Rough/******.csv')

 for i in df.COMPANY_NAME:
    i = i.replace("'","")
    i = i.replace("\\","")
   #i = i.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO polls_company (name) VALUES ('" + i + "')")
 db.commit()
```

This code working fine in some sort of CSV files, but having issues in few CSV files.

**Errors :**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-7-aac849862588> in <module>()
 13     i = i.replace("\\","")
 14     #i = i.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
 ---> 15     cur.execute("INSERT INTO polls_company (name) VALUES ('" + i + "')")
 16 db.commit()

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
 211 
 212         if isinstance(query, unicode):
 --> 213             query = query.encode(db.unicode_literal.charset, 'surrogateescape')
 214 
 215         res = None

 UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 49: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Here, this "Character Encoding" issue is occurred in some CSV files only, but i want automatic Insertion with common encoding techniques.

Because CSV Files encoded works with "utf-8", "latin-1" and more...

If i use **utf-8** : then i got error in **latin-1**
and vise versa

So, Is there any ways to operate all kind of CSV file with common encoding

or

any other ways to solve this ?

[Thanks in Advance...]

Answer (score 1):

I would let the pandas take care of encoding and you don't need to loop through your DF. Let's do it pandas way:

```
import pandas as pd 
import MySQLdb

#Connect with MySQL
db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','****','MY_DB')
cur = db.cursor()

#Reading CSV
df = pd.read_csv('/home/shankar/LAB/Python/Rough/******.csv')

df.COMPANY_NAME.str.replace(r"['\]*", "").rename(columns={'COMPANY_NAME':'name'}).to_sql('polls_company', db, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Then what abt, if i process more than one column means ?

Comment: But this code generate error as "error: unterminated character set at position 0"